# Health Bar in XNA

Tags: xna-4.0

I have a little trouble with my health. When I was moving my personage, the healthbar lasped out of screen. 
How can I keep it standing in my screen,something likes not moving anywhere. But when I move my personage, it'll move, too.

Here my code:

```
 private Texture2D container, lifebar;
    public Vector2 position;
    public int fullHealth;
    public int currentHealth;
    public Healthbar(ContentManager content)
    {
        LoadContent(content);
        fullHealth = lifebar.Width;
        currentHealth = fullHealth;
    }

    private void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
    {
        container = content.Load<Texture2D>("Untitled");
        lifebar = content.Load<Texture2D>("Health 2");

    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
            position.X += 3;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
            position.X -= 3;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(container, position ,Color.Red);
        spriteBatch.Draw(lifebar, position, new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, currentHealth, lifebar.Height), Color.Pink); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `position.x` and `position.y` values with the screen bounds otherwise you will always lose the health bar.  You want something like:

```
if (position.X <= 10)
    position.X = 10;

if (position.X >= 1270)
    position.X = 1270;
```

etc.